# AWK: How do I compute the total hours from a CSV file

Tags: csv, awk, gawk

I have this file which reads

```
001,Time-in,2017-06-25 08:04:42,08:00:00,
001,Time-out,2017-06-25 17:04:42,17:00:00,
001,Time-in,2017-06-25 18:04:42,18:00:00,
001,Time-out,2017-06-25 22:04:42,22:00:00,
...
```

where field 1 is the ID number; 2 is the action performed; 3 is the exact timestamp; and 4 is the rounded off time.

I would like to calculate the total hours per ID based on **field 4**. I know I can use the formula

```
((Out2+Out1)-(In2+In1))
or
((Out1-In1)+(Out2-In2))
```

to get the total hours, but I'm quite stuck as to how I should begin.

I would like to get this output:

```
001,13
002,12
..,..
..,..
```

Where field 1 is the ID and 2 will be the total hours computed.
Also, please note that the real file would be jumbled and not sorted like the example above. If any of the required entries are missing, i.e one time-out missing etc., it should just print that it skipped that particular ID.

Any thoughts regarding this would be extremely helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[-, :]" }
$3=="in"  { tin[$1]  += $10 }
$3=="out" { tout[$1] += $10 }
END {
    for (key in tin) {
        print key, tout[key] - tin[key]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
001 13
```

Comment: Great! works even if the entries are rambled. Mind doing a short explanation? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure, what part of it don't you understand?

Comment: this `t{in,out}[$1]  += $10` #you add up all the hours for {in,out}? Then only in the END block you subtract the hours, that's why regardless of their position in the file, they'd still be computed properly?

Comment: Same response - yes.

Comment: Nice. I think this is as simple as it gets. I'm going to accept your answer. Thanks a lot for your help, and thank you for being patient.

Answer (score 0):

(No error handling or error recovery below.)

I'd probably write a function to return epoch time, given an ISO timestamp. Epoch time makes the arithmetic easy. But it uses the full timestamp, not your rounded values.

```
function epoch_time(ts) {

    gsub("-", " ", ts)
    gsub(":", " ", ts)

    return mktime(ts)
}
```

Assuming we can rely on the format on the input file--a BIG assumption--you can use pretty simple code to select and process each line of the input file.

```
$2 == "Time-in" {
    timein = epoch_time($3)
}

$2 == "Time-out" {
    timeout = epoch_time($3)
    # Add the result to any existing value for this id number.
    # Express in hours.
    output[$1] += (((timeout - timein) / 60) / 60)
}

END {
    for (key in output) print key, output[key] 
}
```

So the full code would look like this,

```
# timestamp.awk
#
$2 == "Time-in" {
    timein = epoch_time($3)
}

$2 == "Time-out" {
    timeout = epoch_time($3)
    # Add the result to any existing value for this id number.
    # Express in hours.
    output[$1] += (((timeout - timein) / 60) / 60)
}

END {
    for (key in output) print key, output[key] 
}

function epoch_time(ts) {

    gsub("-", " ", ts)
    gsub(":", " ", ts)

    return mktime(ts)
}
```

. . . and I'd call it like this.

```
$ awk -F, -f timestamp.awk datafilename
```

For this data, I get the output farther below.

```
001,Time-in,2017-06-25 08:04:42,08:00:00,
001,Time-out,2017-06-25 17:04:42,17:00:00,
001,Time-in,2017-06-25 18:04:42,18:00:00,
001,Time-out,2017-06-25 22:04:42,22:00:00,

002,Time-in,2017-06-25 09:04:42,08:00:00,
002,Time-out,2017-06-25 17:04:42,17:00:00,
002,Time-in,2017-06-25 19:04:42,18:00:00,
002,Time-out,2017-06-25 22:04:42,22:00:00,
```

```
$ awk -F, -f timestamp.awk datafilename
002 11
001 13
```

Comment: I think we're on to something here. I was able to use the 4th field with mktime(); I just padded the dates with zeros. Thanks for putting me in the right direction! Now for the error checking part.

Comment: @ReyLeonardAmorato it's very unclear what that 4th field is useful for when you have an exact timestamp in the 3rd field. Also, if your timestamps can cross day boundaries then you'll clearly need the 3rd field, not the 4th. If you can't cross day boundaries and your 4th field has all the info you need then you don't need mktime() (which is gawk-specific) at all. Edit your question to clarify what the 4th field is for in terms of your current question and why in your pseudo-code you're adding it to the 3rd field before doing the subtractions.

Comment: The 4th field is there to regulate the times of the individual IDs (grace period etc.) Say we have someone clock in at 07:55 and one at 08:10, if we use the exact timestamp, then the one who clocked in at 07:55 will get more hours.

Comment: No he won't, you'd just round down to the nearest hour.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks for mentioning that mktime() was specific to gawk. While I was writing this, I recall thinking I should check on that, but I got distracted and forgot. I replaced Ubuntu's default flavor (mawk?) with gawk a few years ago.

Comment: Then some will get an extra hour and some an hour gone. Though, the issue here is not about which timestamp I should use, but how to compute hours from the data provided.

Comment: The purpose of that field is so that I don't have to do anymore rounding up/down on the times when it comes to the total. Because it's already regulated/adjusted. What you said is for the very purpose of that field.

Comment: OK then theres 2 possibilities: 1) your in/out can cross a day boundary or 2) it can't. If "1" is true then you need to use $3 rather than or in addition to $4 while if "2" is true then you don't need `mktime()`. Which one is true?

Comment: Case 2. Aha. I realised what you were trying to say about mktime(). I'm sorry this dragged on for a while.